# Matriz de Expressão

Tags: r, matriz

Eu tenho a matriz a seguir no R:

```
 FC12h         FC10d        FC6w

-8.44770875  -0.37171750    0
-56.72384575  2.64778150    2.94636550
-3.00214850   2.64778150   -1.57755700
```

Eu preciso de alguma função que faça com que os numeros maiores que zero fiquem com valor igual a 1, menor que zero valor igual a -1, e quando 0 fique igual a 0:

```
  FC12h         FC10d        FC6w

   -1          -1             0
   -1           1             1
   -1           1            -1
```

Alguém sabe como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A maneira mais fácil é com a função `sign`. Mais simples não pode ser:

```
sign(dados)
#  FC12h FC10d FC6w
#1    -1    -1    0
#2    -1     1    1
#3    -1     1   -1
```

**Dados.**

```
dados <- read.table(text = "
FC12h         FC10d        FC6w
-8.44770875  -0.37171750    0
-56.72384575  2.64778150    2.94636550
-3.00214850   2.64778150   -1.57755700
", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: bem mais simples.

Comment: Muito interessante, não sabia dessa função. Vou testar.

Answer (score 3):

Sendo `dados` sua matriz,

```
ifelse(dados < 0, -1, ifelse(dados > 0, 1, 0) )
```

vai retornar o que você espera.

A função `ifelse` está testando se os valores de `dados` são negativos (`dados < 0`). Caso seja verdadeira, será atribuído o valor `-1`, caso contrário, outro teste é realizado. Agora testamos se os valores de `dados` são positivos (`dados > 0`). Caso seja verdadeiro, atribuímos o valor 1, senão será igual a `0`.

O código indentado, usando `if` e `else` fica:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(dados)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(dados)){
    if(dados[i,j] < 0){
      dados[i,j] <- -1
    } else{
      if(dados[i,j] > 0){
        dados[i,j] <- 1
      } else{
        dados[i,j] <- 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oi, não entendi muito bem. Como seria seu código indentado?

Comment: Vlw, cara. Muito obrigado. Deu certo!!!!

Comment: Considere [aceitar](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta) a resposta que te ajudou a resolver o problema.